# How to add a button in gridview to link to web page?

Tags: asp.net

I need to add a button in my gridview in each row and link that to a web page in my website.   Each row would go to a different web page.

Here is my code I have at the moment:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvClients" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="mGrid" AllowPaging="true" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Company" HeaderText="Company" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Last Name" HeaderText="Last Name" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Contact" HeaderText="Contact" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

And in C#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter data = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM clients", conn);
            DataTable datatbl = new DataTable();
            data.Fill(datatbl);
            gvClients.DataSource = datatbl;
            gvClients.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

I am not sure on how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**.aspx Page**

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grdTesting" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="98%">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Job Number">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkTest" runat="server" Text='<% # Bind("Test") %>' ToolTip='<%# Bind("Test") %>'
                            OnClick="lnkTest_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnId" runat="server" Value='<% # Bind("Id") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

**.aspx.cs Page**

```
 protected void lnkTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)((Control)sender).Parent.Parent;
        HiddenField hdnId = (HiddenField)gvr.FindControl("hdnId");

    if(Convert.ToString(hdnId.value)=="1")
    {
            Response.Redirect("frmTest1.aspx?Id=" + Convert.ToString(hdnId.Value), false);
    }

    else if(Convert.ToString(hdnId.value)=="2")
    {
        Response.Redirect("frmTest2.aspx?Id=" + Convert.ToString(hdnId.Value), false);
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("frmTest.aspx?Id=" + Convert.ToString(hdnId.Value), false);
    }
    }
```

**Note:-**

In Page Load,you have to bind GridView(as per your Prefrence..)

Suppose,You have a Gridview with Link Button(which redirect to different Pages...)

So, you have to also bind Id........so can Redirect to Different Pages as Per your ID...

On click of link button you can redirect to other page(as per your Logic..) with sending Query string value(Id)

I'm using asp.net with c# 4.5